# Arduino weather forecast with BMP085 pressure sensor

Tags: arduino

I would like to predict when it will rain using a BMP085 pressure sensor on Arduino. I am using the code found [here](http://bildr.org/2011/06/bmp085-arduino/) which works great.

What I need now is to calculate pressure change over time, if it drops by say, 3hPa in an hour it will probably rain.

How can I keep track of pressure readings in the past and compare to the latest reading?

Comment: You'll want to be taking a reading every few seconds (use delay in loop or TimedAction library) and storing that in internal flash using PROGMEM (because SRAM space is quite limited). Then use a for loop to add up all the values for a given time period (say, an hour) and divide by number of values. You could do this for different hours and easily find the difference between them with simple subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I fully understand what you mean or what is the formula you are using but the way I store date or make a config file for params that over time changes.
And I want to save the last value, in case the `sram` is overfill or the board restarts or maybe the power lost.
Use SD card module (2GB is more then you ever will need)

```
(double)ValueToRefRence = analogRead(SensorPin);
//you can store it to SD 
boolean MayRain = false;
int InsidCount =0;
double ThresHold = 3.00;
while(!MayRain)
{
(double)CurrentRead = analogRead(SensorPin);
delay(TimeIntervel) //Say every 5min
(double)Delta = ValueToRefRence - CurrentRead ;
if (Delta > ThresHold)
{ MayRain = true;}
else if(InsidCount> 100) //for escape and make new reading 
 {break;}
else 
{InsidCounter++;}

}
```